# Textview with rounded left and right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm wondering how to create something like the image below using drawables so I can apply it as background?

[image]

**This isn't a simple rectangle with rounded corners but a kind of a rectangular oval**,

Attempts:

Using a `rectangle`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <size android:width="40dp"
          android:height="10dp" />

    <corners
        android:radius="100dp" />
```

[image]

Using an `oval`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <size android:width="40dp"
          android:height="10dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use shape

Comment: Why would you close my question? I've already checked the other questions but those are quite different as the corners do not meet like this one.

Comment: its just kinda of Rounded Corners' TextView.. and there are several samples available

Comment: I know that it's kind of rounded corners, but this kind of rounded corners aren't possible to be created with corners and paddings as far as i know.

Comment: and why would you downvote?

Comment: Added what I've tried

Comment: to me it seems to be like a custom textview created using nine patch image which is applied to all textview present in application using style

Comment: i think its a rectangle with rounded corners such that *radius of corner circle* = *height of textview /2*

Comment: Without a mathematical description of "a kind of a rectangular oval", I'm not sure how you're going to get a really solid answer. Off the cuff, I agree that it is a rounded rectangle, and you need to increase the corner radius until you're happy with it. You could also do it as a nine-patch PNG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for this you have to change the size of text view, By using the below code I got the result.

Code used in Drawable...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ff2233"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="100dp" />

</shape>
```

Code used in button...

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_click"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sh"
        android:text="Click" />
```

Result: ..........

[image]

Comment: I think it would be a bad idea to set the width and height explicitly.

Comment: No need of that,You can set the width and height drawable itself, In text view Make it as wrap_content. Your width and height should maintain a Ratio.

Comment: Seems to be working, added some extra padding to left and right